# Creating full text index for several columns without query builder in Laravel migration

Tags: laravel-9

Experienced a need of creating full text index for several columns without using query builder in Laravel 9.0 to make decision clearer, however all answers or tips were either for one/two columns or with query builder.

Tips and tutorials didn't work for me as I had 6 columns to create this index and that led to an error :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier name 'table_column1,column2,column3,col...' is too long
```

So my code was:

```
class AddFulltextIndexes extends Migration
{
    private array $fields = [
        'column1',
        'column2',
        'column3',
        'column4',
        'column5',
        'column6'
    ];

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('invoice_cds', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->fullText($this->fields);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who found themselves in similar situation there is an exit:
Laravel allows to create indexes passing the index name as a second parameter, so I changed one line and migration started to work:

```
$table->fullText($this->fields, 'table_full_test_indexes');
```